# Regular expressions - how to match url pages

Tags: regex

I would like to match strings like this:

```
page
page01-page02
page01-page02-page03
page-page/page/page-03-001
p-a-g-e
p/a/g/e
123-456-789/123/123-456-789
p
```

These are allowed strings I want to match. They are divided by `/`, and between each `/` there can be `[a-z0-9]+`, again divided by `-`. It's hard to explain; my examples should make things clearer.

I came up with this regex:

```
/(([a-z0-9]+)(\-[a-z0-9]+){0,})(\/([a-z0-9]+)(\-[a-z0-9]+){0,}){0,}/
```

You can test it [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/ESVqLUFupl).

My regular expression skills aren't that great at the moment and I would like to know if there is a better way of matching these strings. Also, is the regex I have above any good?

Comment: +1 to give us an online tester for your regex flavour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with next regex:

```
^[a-z\d]+((\/|-)[a-z\d]+)*$
```

Explanation:

```
^                      # Begin of match (zero-width)
[a-z\d]+               # One or more combination of letters and digits (not included uppercase).
(
  (\/|-)               # A '/' or '-'
  [a-z\d]+             # One or more combination of letters and digits.
)*                     # All last combination zero or more times.
$                      # End of match (zero-width).
```